# iPad Air - CoreBluetooth[ERROR] Cancelling picker as we couldn't communicate with Bluetooth

Tags: ipad, core-bluetooth, external-accessory

I'm working with the "ExternalAccessory framework".
I encountered a problem trying my app on a new iPad Air.

When i try to show the bluetooth picker this error appear:

```
CoreBluetooth[ERROR] Cancelling picker as we couldn't communicate with Bluetooth
```

The bluetooth is **ON**.
Picker return this error:

```
Error Domain=EABluetoothAccessoryPickerErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be 
completed.
```

My app work on every Apple Device, except the new iPad Air.

### ***EDIT***

I can connect and communicate with my device. The problem appear only if i call the bluetooth picker.

### ***EDIT 2***

the problem appears also with a modified version of EADemo.

I've added this function.

```
- (void)searchDevice {
    [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:nil];
}
```

When i call it, BANG! The same error. <s>Only in **iPad Air**</s>

### ***this problem will occur on all 64-bit devices***

Comment: You got a CoreBluetooth (for Bluetooth Low-Energy) Error with `ExternalAccessory.framework` (for classical Bluetooth) ?

Comment: Yes. It's very strange.

Comment: I think you may report it to Apple.

Comment: Seeing this too in our app (Pebble) on iPhone 5S. I made a quick test app that does nothing but call `-showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:completion:` and it works there. Digging into what's different now.

Comment: I tried removed CoreBluetooth and all its uses from our app. Did solve it. I tried removing the EA protocol identifiers from the info.plist. Did not help. Removed the Bluetooth and EAAcessory related background modes from the info.plist. No cigar. Ended up filing a bug too and requested Dev Tech Support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your app needs to include a 64-bit slice (add `arm64` to the `ARCHS` build setting), otherwise this problem will occur on 64-bit devices like iPhone 5S, iPad Air... This is a bug in iOS 7.0 - 7.0.3. It is supposed to be fixed in the next release.

Comment: YESSSSS! ;) you saved me <3

Comment: i would like to give you 1000 score... ahahah i'll send to you a beer!

Comment: Adding arm64 worked for me...and I am building for iOS 7.1, so does not appear to have been fixed all these months (and a couple of releases) later.

Comment: FYI not fixed in 8.0b2.

Comment: I've gotten confirmation from Apple that they do not consider this a bug and it will **NOT** be fixed in iOS 8 GM. I strongly disagree with the assessment that it is not a bug, but it looks like if you want to use the in-app bluetooth picker you must build for both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Adding both:

```
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
#import <ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory.h>
```

To either the header of implementation fixed this for me.
Very strange because the frameworks are already linked at app launch?..