# Xamarin / iOS SharedAccessoryManager.ShowBluetoothAccessoryPicker Fails

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, external-accessory

I'm porting working Swift code to Xamarin for my project.  Every time I call this function, it fails and the accessory picker dialog doesn't show.

EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager.ShowBluetoothAccessoryPicker(predicate, completion)

Here's some things I've confirmed:

- BT Radio is on
- Info.plist has **Supported external accessory protocols**
- Tried ensuring call is done on UI thread
- Tried calling directly from Button click event
- The same basic code in Swift / Xcode works fine
- Made sure that ARMv7 and ARM64 were selected in build options per this article: [iPad Air - CoreBluetooth[ERROR] Cancelling picker as we couldn't communicate with Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402973/ipad-air-corebluetootherror-cancelling-picker-as-we-couldnt-communicate-wit)

Xamarin:

```
        EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager.ShowBluetoothAccessoryPicker(null, completion: ((Foundation.NSError error) => {
            Console.WriteLine("My callback");   
            if (error != null) {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Error code: {0} Desc: {1}", error.Code, error.DebugDescription));
                Console.WriteLine("Failed? " + EABluetoothAccessoryPickerError.Failed.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Failed? " + Convert.ToInt64(EABluetoothAccessoryPickerError.Failed));
            }
        }));
```

Xcode / Swift:

```
        EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager().showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter(nil) { (error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("Error code: \(error!.code) \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
    }
```

The Xamarin code doesn't show the picker and will always fail.

```
2016-04-05 19:54:02.136 ASGDemo.iOS[6383:2146384] Connect Clicked
2016-04-05 19:54:06.139 ASGDemo.iOS[6383:2146384] BTM: attaching to BTServer
2016-04-05 19:54:09.157 ASGDemo.iOS[6383:2146384] BTM: session attach called back with BT_SESSION_ATTACHED (fffffed0)
2016-04-05 19:54:09.158 ASGDemo.iOS[6383:2146384] BTM: attemping to re-attach in 1 seconds
2016-04-05 19:54:09.242 ASGDemo.iOS[6383:2146384] My callback
2016-04-05 19:54:09.250 ASGDemo.iOS[6383:2146384] Error code: 3 Desc: Error Domain=EABluetoothAccessoryPickerErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"
2016-04-05 19:54:09.253 ASGDemo.iOS[6383:2146384] Failed? Failed
2016-04-05 19:54:09.254 ASGDemo.iOS[6383:2146384] Failed? 3
```

Comment: Could you link your Info.plist from both Xamarin and XCode?

Comment: I presume you call this on a device? What device are you using and what abi do you run on it? According to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402973/ipad-air-corebluetootherror-cancelling-picker-as-we-couldnt-communicate-wit you need to build for both 32 and 64 bit versions. So in Build Options make sure ARMv7 + ARM64 are picked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had previously found the article you referenced and have both ARMv7 and ARM64 selected in the build options. Apologies for not posting that originally. I will edit my original post to add that info. Also, devices I've tried on.  iPad Air 2, running iOS version 9.2.1.  iPhone 6, running iOS version 9.3

Answer (score 0):

The nice folks at Xamarin helped me directly, so I'm posting the solution here.  They said it was a bug that has already been fixed.  The update should ship later this month via automatic updates (if you have that enabled).

For now, they provided a workaround that I've verified to work for me and my co-workers on our project.  Below are the steps of the workaround:

1. **Clean** the project
2. Uncheck the **Enable device-specific builds** in the project options under iOS-Build section.
3. **Remove** old app from the device
4. Now, **rebuild / redeploy** and it should work.

Thank you everyone for your suggestions and help.  Also, thanks to the folks at Xamarin for their prompt response.